# sql update table mysql call from oracle though dg4odbc not working

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I use hs, dg4odbc to query mysql from oracle. Query select mysql from oracle is ok, but my update sql not working.

Mysql database version 5.6.23, oracle database version 12c and my update sql is:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE "user"@mysql 
   SET "avatar" = 'http://...abc.png'
 WHERE "username" = 'abc';
COMMIT;
END;
```

Error ORA-02070: database xxx does not support SYS_OP_C2C in this context
or ORA-02070: database xxx does not support some function in this context

I remember I used method update working well, but now is not working.

Please help me call update mysql from oracle using dg4odbc

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem.

```
DECLARE
  c INTEGER;
  nr INTEGER;
BEGIN
  c := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@mysql;
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@mysql(c,
        'UPDATE user SET avatar=? WHERE username=?');
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@mysql(c,1,'http://...abc.png');
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_VARIABLE@mysql(c,1,'abc');
  nr:=DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@mysql(c);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nr||' rows updated');
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@mysql(c);
END;
```